# Empty folder pushed on Github?

Tags: github, web, repository, mern

I am very new to GitHub and still learning. So I have a folder "Project Code" having client-side and server side applications folder. I have pushed other client-side projects on GitHub successfully.
But when I pushed my "Project Code" folder, I only got empty folders of client-side and server-side on GitHub? Why does this happen?
***How can I push folder having two projects in it?***

Comment: please add sample command what you are doing . by your message it looks like you have not add and commit the files inside your Project Code folder

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.